# Android:Start foreground won't display notification properly

Tags: java, android, notifications

I am working on an application that uses a foreground service.
for this purpose I am calling `startForeground(id,Notification)` from inside onStartCommand callback of the service.

I use a notification builder to create my notification but when I pass it to startForeground only the ticker text is displayed as i set it, everything else turns to default, i.e. the Title says " is running while i had it set to " is online"

Also anything that i had set using the setText and setInfo method in the notification.Builder does not show up instead default text like "touch for more information or to stop the application" shows in its place.

here's the relevant code:

Service :

```
private final int NOTIFICATION_ID=1;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"EDI: Core service Started" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, CoreServiceNotification.getNotification(this, "EDI is online", "Online","Online and running","EDI just started"));
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
```

CoreServiceNotification:

```
public class CoreServiceNotification {

        public static Notification getNotification(Context context,String title,String text,String info,String tickerText){
            Notification.Builder notificationBuilder= new Notification.Builder(context);
            notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(title);
            notificationBuilder.setContentText(text);
            notificationBuilder.setContentInfo(info);
            notificationBuilder.setTicker(tickerText);
            notificationBuilder.setLights(0x00ffff00, 1000, 0);
            return notificationBuilder.build();
        }

    }
```

RESULT:
[image]

Comment: I think you forget to Create `NotificationManager notificationManager;` Object then you have to add like `notificationManager.notify("1",notificationBuilder);`

Comment: No, I am passing the notification object to StartForeground method of the service see the method here [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html )

Comment: then what is your problem?

Comment: please read the question ! the text i set is not what is showed in actual notification

Comment: ohh i did not see sorry!

Comment: I have the same problem, did you ever resolve it?

Comment: Try calling `notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)` before building the notification and calling `startForeground()`, it fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I think it's necessary to set the smallIcon first when you create the notification.

```
Notification.Builder notificationBuilder= new Notification.Builder(context);
notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.yourIcon);
// then set other staff...
```

Here is another simple example from Cousera Android class,
[Click here](https://github.com/Kleagleguo/coursera-android/blob/master/Examples/MusicPlayingServiceExample/src/course/examples/Services/MusicService/MusicService.java)

Comment: Setting smallIcon as first doesn't help to avoid the exception!

Comment: idk how this beat my issue. anyways basketful thanks from me.

Comment: I found that it is no longer necessary to set it first in Android 8.1, but it is necessary to set it - or other settings, like Intents(!) are ignored.